# Reset session timeout in Websphere by Keypress / Mouse events

Tags: session, jakarta-ee, websphere-7, httpsession

I have set the session timeout in my WebSphere as 3 Mins (Consider.Actual timeout I have set is 30 mins).I have kept my application open and just moving my mouse over the J2EE application and making some keypress which will not submit any pages.Even after 3 mins, the session of the application is retained.I need to confirm how the session is retained when some mouse move / keypress happens ? No request is being sent to server or no page submissions has been done.

The session timeout for my application is maintained only in server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like it's due to WebSphere's use of the LTPA token for authentication.  In summary:

- When the web session expires a users credentials are not expired (you
  are not forced to re-login).  This is due to the WebSphere
  implementation of LTPA tokens and more info on this is covered in the
  IBM documentation.
- When the LTPA token expires the users credentials
  are expired (you are forced to re-login).
- The web session timeout is
  relative to user activity. That is, it resets to 0 when user activity
  is detected.
- LTPA token timeout is not related to user activity. It
  will timeout after the amount of time from creation date no matter
  what user activity is going on.

From http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21078845:

**Question 3**

I want to force my users to re-login after a set "inactivity timeout" period. How is WebSphere Application Server supposed to work with regard to session timeouts and LTPA timeout.

**Answer 3**

See the answer to this question in item 9 of the following developerworks article:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/1003_botzum/1003_botzum.html

From that link you learn:

**9- I want to force my users to login again after a set "inactivity timeout" period. How is WebSphere Application Server supposed to work with regard to session timeouts and LTPA timeouts?**

The WebSphere Application Server LTPA token expires based on the lifetime of the login session, not based upon inactivity. Thus, the WebSphere Application Server login session will not expire if the user performs no action for some period of time. However, the HTTPSession does expire based upon inactivity. If in your application you need to expire the use of an application based on idleness, you must explicitly code this in your application. You can capture when a user arrives with an expired session (really, a new session) and force them to login again if you think this is necessary. Keep in mind that doing this undermines Single Sign On across applications.

A second approach that is a slight variation on the first is to use HTTPSession.getLastAccessTime() to compute when the last client request occurred. If the time is too far into the past, you can of course fail the access and force a new authentication.
Either of these approaches can be made transparent to the application code through the use of servlet filters.

It should be noted that IBM Tivoli® Access Manager provides for lifetime- and idle-based authentication session timeouts.

Users often ask why WebSphere Application Server works this way. Why can't it timeout idle login sessions? The reason is because WebSphere Application Server is fundamentally a loosely coupled distributed system. Application servers that participate in an SSO domain don't need to talk to each other. They don't even have to be in the same cell. So, if you want to limit the idleness lifetime of an LTPA token (aka SSO token), you'd have to update the token itself with a last usage time on every request (or perhaps on the first request seen during a one minute interval). This means that the token itself would change frequently (meaning the browser would be accepting new cookies frequently) and that WebSphere Application Server would have to decrypt and verify the inbound token when it is seen to validate it. That could be expensive (WebSphere Application Server today only validates a token on the first use at each application server). It's not impossible to solve these problems with clever caching and such, but that's not how WebSphere Application Server works today.